# How to install a module on python (windows 7)

Tags: python, windows, faker

I've installed python 3.4 on win7. I need faker module to be installed to run the script.

error:
from faker import Factory
ImportError: No module named 'faker'.

I've downloaded few zip's with faker, but unfortunately have no idea how to install it.
Please give simple instructions, how to make it work.(on windows)

Comment: Also, where did you download the zip for faker from? And what zip?

Comment: https://github.com/joke2k/faker  for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have downloaded the zip source from https://github.com/joke2k/faker according to your comments , you can also do the following after changing to the directory where you have setup.py -

```
python setup.py install
```

According to the github page itself, to install using `pip` do -

```
pip install fake-factory
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Python package tool `pip`.

Open a command prompt and do

```
pip install fake-factory
```

or

```
python -m pip install fake-factory
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/) for more information.